# put information from datatable into gridview

Tags: search, gridview, datatable

I'm writing a simple search algorithm to display the results that contain the value typed into a text box.

I am trying to place information from a datatable into a gridview's boundfield elements.
the code i have to display the search results:

```asp
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SimpleSearch.ascx.cs"Inherits="SimpleSearch" %>

 <asp:TextBox ID="SimpleSearchBox" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="submitSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
        onClick="SimpSearch" />


            <asp:Gridview ID="results" runat="server" Visible="false" >

            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="Path" headerText="Path" SortExpression="Path" />

            </Columns>

        </asp:Gridview>
        <label ID="errMsg" runat="server" />
```

but i think the real trouble is coming from my code-behind:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;    
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

public partial class SimpleSearch : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void SimpSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // retrieve the connection string from our config file
    string connString =
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GeoNames"].ConnectionString;
    // retrieve the provider name from config file
    string providerName =
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GeoNames"].ProviderName;
    // get the factory based on the provider name
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
    // create the connection
    DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connString;
    //get text from search box
    string query = SimpleSearchBox.Text;
    try
    {
        // define the SQL command1
        string sql = "SELECT Title, td.ImageID, ti.ImageID, Description FROM TravelImageDetails as td, TravelImage as ti";
        sql += " WHERE td.ImageID = ti.ImageID AND td.Title LIKE '%@query%' OR td.Description LIKE'%@query%' ";
        // create a command
        DbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        // create the data adapter
        DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        // fill a data table from the adapter
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        results.DataSource = dt;
        results.DataBind();
        results.Visible = true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errMsg.InnerText = "<h2>An Error Occurred</h2>";
        errMsg.InnerText += ex.Message;
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
}
```

clicking the search button shows no data and i am wondering why it wont do anything. Any input would be helpful, my skills in c# are very limited